# Why does my service keeps running

Tags: android

I have developed an app which runs a service on click of a button and which in turns Async task.  I have seen many times that even when long after not using the app my service is shown in running apps tab of settings menu.  It is shown as 0 process and 1 service running for as long as 100 hrs.

I am using non sticky service.  I am confused under what scenario something like this can happen.  I am calling stop self in post execute event handler on Async Task.

My question is how can I troubleshoot this?  Should not just service stop after Async task is executed.  Under what scenario this can happen?

Update:

The following is the service code:
https://github.com/madhur/wundersync/blob/master/src/in/co/madhur/wunderlistsync/service/WunderSyncService.java

Comment: Please provide a small piece of code that demonstrates how you use a service. `Service#stopSelf` does work if used correctly (e.g. if you provide a start id it must be the one from the latest start or it's not stopping)

Comment: maybe you are leaking it.

Comment: do you actually stop the service ?

Comment: In most cases, using `IntentService` is a better solution than using a combination of `Service` and an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I have provided the code link